Reason for Accurate but Partial Solution to $Ax = b$?
I am solving the following linear equation:
$$\mathbf{A} \:\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}, \quad \mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}, \: \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N \text{ and } \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^M \text{ with } M \gg N.$$
Now $\mathbf{A}$ in column rank-deficient. The "least square" solution, $(\mathbf{A}^T \: \mathbf{A})^{\dagger} \: \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b}$, gives me a part which is exactly what I am looking for. More concretely, let's say the solution I am looking for is $\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 
x_1 & \ldots & x_K & x_{K + 1} & \ldots & x_N 
\end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbf{x}^T_a & \mathbf{x}^T_b 
\end{bmatrix}^T$. Representing the estimated solution with the hat symbol on top, I get $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_a$ correctly.
Question: Why do I always get part of the solution corresponding to $\mathbf{x}_a$ correct? Somehow the ambiguity due to the rank deficiency of $\mathbf{A}$ is reflected only when estimating $\mathbf{x}_b$. Moreover, it seems like I should be able to split $\mathbf{A}$ in two parts somehow to get $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_a = \mathbf{x}_a$ 'uniquely' while $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_b$ is in some 'least squares best fit' sense which is not the same as the solution I am looking for, i.e. $\mathbf{x}_b$. How can I do it?
Any insight is welcome!!!
My thoughts: Think in terms of subspaces. Matrix $\mathbf{A}$ being rank deficient implies that the kernel space of $\mathbf{A}$ is not empty. The fact that the least squares solution $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_a$ is unique and correct implies a situation that I would like to explain through an example. Say we have a $2D$ space and for a similar problem we are looking for a solution $\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_a & x_b
\end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b
\end{bmatrix}^T$. What happens if the kernel space of $\mathbf{A}$ is the plane $x_a = a$. My least squares estimate will be $\hat{\mathbf{x}} = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x}_a = a & \hat{x}_b
\end{bmatrix}^T$ where $\hat{x}_b$ will be a point in some least square best-fit sense. So the second part of my question becomes, how can I claim $\hat{x}_a$ is the true solution I am looking for and all ambiguity is in $\hat{x}_b$ for my general case?
EDIT 1: Please do not give me the least squares solution. If you read my solution, it is the least squares one!
EDIT 2: I have given my thoughts/ a line of thinking on the likely case. There must be some theorem directly stating that and identifying the subspace I refer to!

@YvesDaoust I don't think the degree of rank deficiency is important but I can give you the asnwer. $\mathbf{A}$ is not rank deficient by a lot. By estimated solution, I mean the least squares solution I write as $(\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A})^{-1} \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b}$.

@YvesDaoust Please check the 'My thoughts' part to understand what I am looking for!

@YvesDaoust Well then help me make it better. What does your comment do?

@YvesDaoust Does the new edit make it any better?

@YvesDaoust I don't mean that $\mathbf{b}$ is not relevant to the solution. I meant to only say that i tried different reasonable noise levels. For sure it depends on $\mathbf{b}$ as you can see with the least squares solution. Let me rephrase it!

The method you're seeking is probably known as least squares method.
Assume there are some $(n+1)$-dimensional data points, and for each data point, there is a dependent variable $y$ which depends linearly on the other $n$ independent variables $x_i$, where $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$. That is
$$y = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \dots + \beta_n x_n + \varepsilon \tag{1}$$
where $\varepsilon$ is a random error.
Let $m$ be the number of such data points. When we have $m$ such $1\times n$ data points $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, \dots, \mathbf{x}_m$ (usually $m \gg n$), we can substitute the equation $(1)$, and give a system of linear equations
$$
\left\{\begin{align}
y_1 &= \beta_1 x_{1,1} + \beta_2 x_{1,2} + \dots + \beta_n x_{1,n} + \varepsilon_1 \\
y_2 &= \beta_1 x_{2,1} + \beta_2 x_{2,2} + \dots + \beta_n x_{2,n} + \varepsilon_2 \\
\vdots \\
y_m &= \beta_1 x_{m,1} + \beta_2 x_{m,2} + \dots + \beta_n x_{m,n} + \varepsilon_m \\
\end{align}\right. \tag{2}
$$
We can then rewrite it into matrix form
$$\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon} \tag{2*}$$
where $\mathbf{X}_{m\times n} = \left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf{x}_1^T & \mathbf{x}_2^T & \dots & \mathbf{x}_m^T\end{matrix}\right]^T$ is known independent variables,
$\mathbf{y}_{m\times 1} = \left[\begin{matrix}y_1 & y_2 & \dots & y_m\end{matrix}\right]^T$ is observed dependent variables,
$\boldsymbol{\beta}_{n\times 1} = \left[\begin{matrix}\beta_1 & \beta_2 & \dots & \beta_m\end{matrix}\right]^T$ is parameters to estimate,
and $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{m\times 1} = \left[\begin{matrix}\varepsilon_1 & \varepsilon_2 & \dots & \varepsilon_m\end{matrix}\right]^T$ is unknown random error.

Now we want to estimate parameters $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ to minimize the sum of squares of the components of residual $\hat{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}} = \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$. In other words, we want to get
$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = \mathop{\arg\min}_{\boldsymbol{\beta}\in\mathbb{R}^n} \hat{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}^T \hat{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}} = \mathop{\arg\min}_{\boldsymbol{\beta}\in\mathbb{R}^n} \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)^T \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right) \tag{3}$$
Consider finding solution of the matrix derivative equation below:
$$\frac{\partial \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)^T \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)}{\partial \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}} = \boldsymbol{0} \tag{4}$$
Perform the following matrix differential calculations
$$\small
\begin{align}
d \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)^T \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right) &= \mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(d \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)^T \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)\right) \\
&= \mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(d \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)^T \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)\right) + \mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)^T d \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)\right) \\
&= \mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\left(d \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)\right)^T \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)\right) + \mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)^T d \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)\right) \\
&= 2 \mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)^T d \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)\right) \\
&= 2 \mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)^T \left(-\mathbf{X}\right) d \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right) \\
&= \mathop{\mathrm{tr}}\left(\left(-2 \mathbf{X}^T \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)\right)^T d \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right) \\
\end{align} \tag{5}$$
Therefore, the matrix derivative
$$\frac{\partial \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)^T \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right)}{\partial \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}} = -2 \mathbf{X}^T \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\right) \tag{6}$$
Puts equation $(6)$ to equation $(4)$ and immediately yields the equation
$$\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{y} \tag{7}$$
Notice that if the rank of $X$ is $n$, then the rank of the $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X}$ is also $n$, thus invertible. And therefore, we can get the estimation of parameters $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ minimizing $\hat{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}^T \hat{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}$:
$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = \left( \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{y} \tag{8}$$
This is the least squares formula.
By replacing $\mathbf{X}$ with $\mathbf{A}$, $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ with $\mathbf{x}$, and $\mathbf{y}$ with  $\mathbf{b}$, you can get exactly the same equation in the question.

Indeed, there is a conclusion that the least squares method gives an unbiased estimate of $y$ in a linear model when the errors are normally distributed, uncorrelated, and have equal variances and a mean of zero. This is called Gauss–Markov theorem.
So when you add some noise (especially normally distributed, uncorrelated, and have equal variances and a mean of zero) into the RHS $b$ of the system of linear equations, it makes sense that the solution wouldn't change.

No. I have already given you the least square solution. What did you find unclear in my question that led to this confusion? If you let me know, I can improve my question!
